# CubeIDE удаляет код после переконфигурации проекта

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

Использую программу CubeIDE для программирования микроконтроллеров для STM32 при переконфигурации проекта (например подключения еще одного пина) возникает неприятная ситуация, а именно удаляется весь написанный код.

```
 /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    // Отсюда все удаляется
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

По идее, внутри комментариев USER CODE ничего не должно удаляться. Что делать с данной проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде есть специальные метки, которые показывают, куда можно вставлять свой код. Например:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

/* USER CODE END 3 */
```

Нужно просто вставлять свой код между этими метками. Тогда ничего не удалится.